# CSS Photo Gallery Floating Issue - MIxing Landscape & Portrait Photos

Tags: jquery, css, css-float, image-gallery, photo-gallery

Whats up everybody,

So I've been struggling with this for a bit and can't seem to get it.

I want to have a photo gallery that fits Landscape & Portrait photos together & doesn't leave any blank space (unless of course on the very end of the gallery if necessary).

We'll be resizing the images that are pulled in to 2 sizes (seen in the css below)...but then i can't figure out how to place them together to fit nicely.

I'm open to any ideas (so it doesn't necessarily have to be just css - although that would be preferred if its possible).  This may be something small i'm overlooking.  But the code is below - Notice the blank spaces between the photos when a portrait photo can't float all the way to the left.

Thanks a ton...

```
#galleryrow {
float: left;
width: 690px;
height: 1600px;
background-color: lightyellow;
margin-left: 60px;
}

#galleryrow img.portrait { 
float: left;
background-color: white;
height: 300px; /*  Height = 300 + 13 + 13 = 326  */
width: 200px; /* Width = 200 + 12 + 12 = 224  */
padding: 13px 12px;
margin-right: 4px;
margin-bottom: 4px;
border: 1px dashed lightgrey;
}

#galleryrow img.portrait:hover {
background-color: #e5e8e7;
height: 300px;
width: 200px;
}

#galleryrow img.landscape {
background-color: white;
height: 130px; /* Height = 130 + 15 + 15 = 160    Multiply by 2 stacked = 320  */
width: 200px;
padding: 15px 12px;
border: 1px dashed lightgrey;

}

#galleryrow img.landscape:hover {
background-color: #e5e8e7;
height: 130px;
width: 200px;
padding: 15px 12px;
}

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Image Gallery w/ Floats</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="floatgallery.css">
</head>

<div id="galleryrow">
        <a href="#"><img class="landscape" src="jetsetter.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="landscape" src="jetsetter.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="portrait" src="philadelphia_skyline1.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="landscape" src="jetsetter.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="landscape" src="jetsetter.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="landscape" src="jetsetter.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="portrait" src="philadelphia_skyline1.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="portrait" src="philadelphia_skyline1.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="portrait" src="philadelphia_skyline1.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="portrait" src="philadelphia_skyline1.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="landscape" src="jetsetter.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="landscape" src="jetsetter.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="portrait" src="philadelphia_skyline1.jpg"></a>
</div>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove float left from #galleryrow and added float left to img.landscape as below. Try it.

```
#galleryrow {
 /*float: left;*/
}

#galleryrow img.landscape {
 float: left;
}
```

Comment: Hey Shankar...this didn't seem to work for me.  There are still gaps in between photos in places...does that work for you?